# .Htaccess redirect rule for server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

I have a folder with the name `img` for which I use this htaccess rule:

```
RewriteRule ^any/new_path/img/(.*) img/$1 [L]
```

To change the URL to `files/modifications/img/`

Inside `img` folder there is a folder called `cars`

When I enter `any/new_path/img/car` in the address bar it redirects to `img/car` and the URL is changed to the new URL and also shows a blank page.

What is the problem?

Comment: Could you provide a few more examples please of input URL and actual vs expected outcome?

Comment: sorry it was a folder not file